# No such file or directory- Shell Script

Tags: shell, sh

Please review my script below am getting `No such file or directory` error when executing it

*Script.sh*

```
_user="$(id -u -n)"
_uid="$(id -u)"
echo "User name : $_user"
echo "User name ID (UID) : $_uid"
REPOSITORIES= `/Users/$_user/workspace/work-folder/`
echo "$REPOSITORIES"

Output

$ ./user-name.sh
User name : 123456
User name ID (UID) : 8092
./user-name.sh: line 6: /Users/123456/workspace/work-folder/: No such file or directory
```

Can you please help, am still new to shell scripting.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your use of back-quotes around `/home/$_user/...` makes me think you want the `$_user` to be expanded to its correct value. But recall that backquotes are for command-substitution and any string inside (or inside modern `$( .. cmd ...)` ) will be executed as a command. That is why you are getting the error message you have. As pointed out below, variables values are expanded in assignments when the variable is not "hidden" from the shell by single-quoting or an escape char `"\"` You want `var="/home/_$user/..."` . Good luck.

Comment: Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ with your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

`REPOSITORIES="/Users/$_user/workspace/work-folder/"`

Quotes makes difference, use double quotes when you are going to use variable in it. And also important, make sure you don't put space after and before equal sign as well.